# I cant calculate "Loss" in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, data-science

Here is my code:

```
# Library Imports
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
plt.style.use("ggplot")

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout

# Loading/Reading in the Data
df = pd.read_csv("BTC-USD.csv")


# Data Preprocessing
### Setting the datetime index as the date, only selecting the 'Close' column, then only the last 1000 closing prices.
df = df.set_index("Date")[['Close']].tail(3000)
df = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df.index))

# Normalizing/Scaling the Data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
df = pd.DataFrame(scaler.fit_transform(df), columns=df.columns, index=df.index)


def visualize_training_results(results):
    """
    Plots the loss and accuracy for the training and testing data
    """
    history = results.history
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
    plt.plot(history['val_loss'])
    plt.plot(history['loss'])
    plt.legend(['val_loss', 'loss'])
    plt.title('Loss')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Loss')
    plt.show()
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
    plt.plot(history['val_accuracy'])
    plt.plot(history['accuracy'])
    plt.legend(['val_accuracy', 'accuracy'])
    plt.title('Accuracy')
    plt.xlabel('Epochs')
    plt.ylabel('Accuracy')
    plt.show()
    
    
def split_sequence(seq, n_steps_in, n_steps_out):
    """
    Splits the univariate time sequence
    """
    X, y = [], []
    
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        end = i + n_steps_in
        out_end = end + n_steps_out
        
        if out_end > len(seq):
            break
        
        seq_x, seq_y = seq[i:end], seq[end:out_end]
        
        X.append(seq_x)
        y.append(seq_y)
    
    return np.array(X), np.array(y)


def layer_maker(n_layers, n_nodes, activation, drop=None, d_rate=.5):
    """
    Create a specified number of hidden layers for an RNN
    Optional: Adds regularization option, dropout layer to prevent potential overfitting if necessary
    """
    
    # Creating the specified number of hidden layers with the specified number of nodes
    for x in range(1,n_layers+1):
        model.add(LSTM(n_nodes, activation=activation, return_sequences=True))

        # Adds a Dropout layer after every Nth hidden layer (the 'drop' variable)
        try:
            if x % drop == 0:
                model.add(Dropout(d_rate))
        except:
            pass

# How many periods looking back to train
n_per_in  = 30

# How many periods ahead to predict
n_per_out = 10

# Features (in this case it's 1 because there is only one feature: price)
n_features = 1

# Splitting the data into appropriate sequences
X, y = split_sequence(list(df.Close), n_per_in, n_per_out)

# Reshaping the X variable from 2D to 3D
X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[1], n_features))

# Instantiating the model
model = Sequential()

# Activation
activ = "softsign"

# Input layer
model.add(LSTM(30, activation=activ, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(n_per_in, n_features)))

# Hidden layers
layer_maker(n_layers=6, n_nodes=12, activation=activ)

# Final Hidden layer
model.add(LSTM(10, activation=activ))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(n_per_out))

# Model summary
model.summary()

plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))


#Im compiling the code here before training
model.compile()
#visualize_training_results(res)
res = model.fit(X, y, epochs=800, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)
#visualize_training_results(res)
```

what exactly do i need to do here so i can start training my model?

I also tried this code to compile:

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=[
        metrics.MeanSquaredError(),
        metrics.AUC(),
    ]
)
```

But when i run this i get metrics not defined error.
Even though i define it right there in the compile function?

And i also did

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

which starts the training but i get this output

```
Epoch 6/800
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 53ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
Epoch 7/800
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 43ms/step - loss: nan - val_loss: nan
```

And when i do this:

```
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I get this output

```
0/10 [==============================] - 0s 49ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1128 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0606
Epoch 121/800
10/10 [==============================] - 0s 48ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1086 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0606
```

It trains and the accuracy works, but i still get nan for loss and val_loss

No matter what compile function parameters i use this thing isnt calculating the loss

Now i tried this

```
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss='mean_squared_error',
    metrics=["accuracy"],
)
```

and this is what i get

```
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 74ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0953 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0606
Epoch 5/800
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 74ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.1097 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0606
Epoch 6/800
10/10 [==============================] - 1s 72ms/step - loss: nan - accuracy: 0.0929 - val_loss: nan - val_accuracy: 0.0606
```

Comment: Try just importing keras at the top like `import keras`

Comment: Most, if not all, of what you're doing is covered in the TF and Keras user documentation.  "Something is wrong" suggests that you haven't yet worked carefully through those user guides -- you should have a Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a clear description of where things go wrong for you.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons why you can obtain NaNs when training your model.

- the data
- loss function returning greater/smaller than +infinity/-infinity

Try to take 20 rows, make sure you looked at each line yourself with your very hooman eyes and then run the code to see if you still get NANs. If you don't, then there may be 1-2 corrupted entries. Else, look what `split_sequence` returns when using only those 20 columns.

Then there is the infinity problem, which leads to NANs. Try to use loss functions that are [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_function).

[Here is a list of Keras loss functions](https://keras.io/api/losses/)

While Root-mean-square deviation returns a value which "represent the error in a natural way compared to the input data" `i.e. RMSE 30'000 <=> error in estimating house price by 30'000$`, it still computes the square, which definitely can go up to infinity too quick, so it's not a solution if that's the issue here. You may use the MAE to keep it low.

UPDATE:

It worked for me. I used the following, along with a similar dataset for another cryptoboy coin in the USA:

```
# The good old SGD and MAE. 
model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mae") # optional: metrics=['accuracy']
```

Be careful when using Adams/Huber or other optimizers/loss functions. You should understand how they operate, at least get the how and why we use them. Now, using the SGD isn't the best, but from there you have a healthy base to start from.

Good luck with your endeavour! Don't overfit, make small model with tiny datasets to quickly train and prototype before running 800 epochs only to find out one parameter was not viable! **PROTO-TYPE**! Future you will thank you! :)

Comment: didi you use this compile function model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mae")?

Comment: To be exact: "model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="mae", metrics=['accuracy'])" But yes, that's it.

Comment: Date         Open         High  ...        Close    Adj Close        Volume
0   2020-03-14  5573.077637  5625.226563  ...  5200.366211  5200.366211  3.615451e+10

Comment: You may not like it but the only option is: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html

10 minutes. And you'll be able to investigate your data. I got my last job BECAUSE i knew how to use pandas. So maybe you'll get a good job too just by having this on Linkedin. ;)

Comment: I could not know your data came from yahoo finance. And Stackoverflow discourages helpers from taking whole codes just to run them on their computer. I already helped you far beyond what anyone on this website is allowed to do. ;)

Comment: how else does anyone know what my issue is without pasting the code- here is a link to the tutorial i use: https://towardsdatascience.com/predicting-bitcoin-prices-with-deep-learning-438bc3cf9a6f I try to make this tutorial work. and yes i appreciate your help, but after 24 hours, i still dont have my coode running

Comment: Try this one: https://keras.io/examples/vision/image_classification_from_scratch/
It was made by the core developers of Keras. it works and it works very well. As I can see it, you don't understand how the loss function nor the optimizer works. You must learn about opti and loss before going into this kind of stuff. In fact, it would be great to start with a simple linear regression first: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html

Comment: i need my loss to say anything other than nan